# Python 3 tk entry system error with accent word

Tags: python, python-3.x, tk-toolkit, tkinter-entry

**hello, Is there any way to put words with accent on value entry in python?

```
**__author__ = 'jordiponsisala'
from tkinter import  *

root= Tk()
root.geometry('500x300+10+10')


entrada = StringVar()

entEntrada = Entry(root,textvariable=entrada).place(x=70,y=70)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answer but I do not need unicode. 
**Python 3 accepts unicode or latin characters without any coding.** 
The problem is that mac osx python Mavericks have a problem with tkinter libraries. 
The solution is to update the version of tcl tk to 8.5.15.1 
Here I leave the address to download: 
https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/

For Mac users from the console to check if there is an error: 
python3 -m idlelib.idle

Python 3 natively install the 8.5 version of tcl tk if i put the 8.6 does not recognize. 
other method to know the version is to run this code: 
import tkinter 
tkinter._test ()

**After update ActiveTcl8.5.15.1.297588-macosx10.5-i386-x86_64-threaded.dmg can this written any accent character in a text field of tkinter without problem and without coding anything.**

I feel aber asked a question that I asked maybe wrong :)

Answer (score -1):

Sure, you must use UNICODE. Take a look at [Python's docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html). There are many examples and ways to use it, but quite probably this example will be enough for you on how to declare your encoding to use in documents (UTF-( is default, but since you speak a latin language, latin-1 is probably more suitable for you):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

u = 'abcdé'
print(ord(u[-1]))
```